# Using subprocess on Popen option

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I use python 2.7 and ffmpeg on Mac OS 10.10.
When use some command from python, coded like below

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd.strip().split(" "))
```

This goes well all the time, but not in ffmpeg filter_complex case.
Below code can run on the terminal with directly input.

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex " nullsrc=size=1920x1440 [base]; [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1440 [frame0];[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x480 [frame1]; [base] [frame0] overlay=shortest=1:x=1920:y=1440 [tmp1]; [tmp1] [frame1] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=480  output.mp4
```

But cannot run with python Popen script like below.

```
cmd = "ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex " nullsrc=size=1920x1440 [base]; [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1440 [frame0];[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x480 [frame1]; [base] [frame0] overlay=shortest=1:x=1920:y=1440 [tmp1]; [tmp1] [frame1] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=480  output.mp4"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd.strip().split(" "))
```

This has problem at split(" ") works unexpected subdivision.
So I prepare the split command directly like

```
split_cmd = [ffmpeg_exe,'-i','input1.mp4','-i','input2.mp4','-filter_complex','\" nullsrc=size=1920x1440 [base]; [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1440 [frame0];[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x480 [frame1]; [base] [frame0] overlay=shortest=1:x=1920:y=1440 [tmp1]; [tmp1] [frame1] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=480\"','output.mp4'];
p = subprocess.Popen(split_cmd)
```

Even in this case, system return

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fb1c9f000c0] No such filter: '" nullsrc' 
Error configuring filters.
```

this could be system confused the -filter_complex option as ffmpeg option.
Anyone can help this, please.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually passing in the opening and closing double-quote `"`, since there is no shell in-between that uses them. Use just

```
' nullsrc=size=1920x1440 [base]; [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1440 [frame0];[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x480 [frame1]; [base] [frame0] overlay=shortest=1:x=1920:y=1440 [tmp1]; [tmp1] [frame1] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=480'
```

instead, i.e. without the opening and closing `\"`.

```
split_cmd = [ffmpeg_exe,'-i','input1.mp4','-i','input2.mp4','-filter_complex',' nullsrc=size=1920x1440 [base]; [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1440 [frame0];[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x480 [frame1]; [base] [frame0] overlay=shortest=1:x=1920:y=1440 [tmp1]; [tmp1] [frame1] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=480','output.mp4']
```

You can also try using [shlex.split](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/shlex.html#shlex.split), as described in the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).

Comment: @yumyumyum my pleasure. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.